# Localhost Your connection is not private

Tags: certificate, chromium

I am trying to access the Argo CD on my https://127.0.0.1:8080/ and got the following error message: 
[image]

I forwarded the port as suggested on the https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/getting_started/ website:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443
```

I also installed the Argo CD certificate, as you can see on the bottom: 
[image]

When I try to access via Firefox, then it works:
[image]

Why with Chromium does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Argo (and most things) will create a self-signed HTTPS certificate. This makes setup easier, but since it's not signed by a trusted source, you get this error. You can either give Argo a real cert directly, or use something like the Ingress system to terminate TLS (or both). Check out cert-manager for issuing LetsEncrypt certs in Kubernetes.

Comment: What is the easiest way?

Comment: The easiest step would be to disable HTTPS, if you're already accessing it via a port-forward tunnel, it doesn't add much.

Comment: How to setup without https?

Comment: `Edit the argocd-server deployment to add the --insecure flag to the argocd-server command` https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/ingress/#kubernetesingress-nginx

Answer (score 7):

The certificate appears invalid (self signed) in either browser. I believe by default Chrome blocks self signed certificates against localhost "for users protection" https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3321715?hl=en. Changing the setting `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` should allow you to access the site on Chrome.

Firefox will show a warning, but does not block users from using an insecure site by default.